# Change amount of time before log out

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate, logout

Is there a way I can change the amount of time before I am logged out?

I use gnome-session-quit.

It is currently set for 1 minute.

I would like to set time to less than 60 seconds.

Answer (score -2):

Try something like

```
at now +30 minute
at> gnome-session-quit
at> <EOT>
```

Install at if not already.

Comment: $at now +30 seconds
at> gnome-session-quit                      
at> <EOT>   /home/andy/bin/Fast_LogOut.sh: line 6: now: command not found
Garbled time
/home/andy/bin/Fast_LogOut.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/home/andy/bin/Fast_LogOut.sh: line 8: `at> <EOT>'

Comment: "seconds" is an invalid option 

Try this:
        echo "gnome-session-quit"|at now+1 minute

Comment: @ A S K I wanted a time less than 60 seconds.